# Pass mouse click event through a shape

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a project where i need 
to make circles and relate between them with cubicCurve
as shown in this image:
[image]

And i need to pass mouseclick events through the part of the cubicCurve colored with "ALICEBLUE", but still being able to pass mouseclick events to the Line colored with "BLACK".

cubicCurve Code:

```
public class transLine extends CubicCurve {

private Polygon polygon;
private Circle to;
private Circle from;
private double arrowHeadTransLength;

public Circle getTo() {
    return to;
}

public void setTo(Circle to) {
    this.to = to;
}

public Circle getFrom() {
    return from;
}

public void setFrom(Circle from) {
    this.from = from;
}

public transLine() {

    setStroke(Color.BLACK);       
    setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);

    // doesn't work because i can't pass click event to the black line
    setMouseTransparent(true);

    // just arrow head part
    polygon = new Polygon();
    fixPolygon();


}

public void fixPolygon(){
    Point2D A = new Point2D(getEndX(),getEndY());
    Point2D Ap = new Point2D(getControlX2(),getControlY2());
    Point2D Ms = getMSecond(A,Ap,arrowHeadTransLength);

    Point2D P1 = getRotatePoint(Ms, A, Math.PI/7);
    Point2D P2 = getRotatePoint(Ms, A, -Math.PI/7);
    getPolygon().getPoints().setAll(new Double[]           
    {A.getX(),A.getY(),P1.getX(),P1.getY(),P2.getX(),P2.getY()});
}

public Point2D getMSecond(Point2D A, Point2D B, double r){
    if( A.getX()==B.getX() && A.getY()==B.getY() ){
        return B;
    }
    double a = (A.getY()-B.getY())/(A.getX()-B.getX());
    double b = A.getY()-a*A.getX();

    double xs = -r*(A.getX()-B.getX())/A.distance(B)+A.getX();
    double ys = a*xs+b;

    return new Point2D(xs,ys);
}

public Point2D getRotatePoint(Point2D P, Point2D O, double theta){
    double rx = Math.cos(theta)*(P.getX()-O.getX()) - Math.sin(theta)* 
                (P.getY()-O.getY()) + O.getX();
    double ry = Math.sin(theta)*(P.getX()-O.getX()) + Math.cos(theta)*
                (P.getY()-O.getY()) + O.getY();
    return new Point2D(rx,ry);
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking or what exactly it is you're trying to do. If you don't get a decent solution soon, please consider clarifying your question a bit.

Comment: see this code "setMouseTransparent(true);"
i want something like that but just for the part colored with "ALICEBLUE"

Comment: Can you please tell me the name of the library you're using? Or is it your own project? Can you provide a link? :-)

Comment: I think to do this you will need two separate shapes; one for the curve and one for the filled part; place them both into a `Group`. Then make the mouse transparent on the filled part.

Comment: @GGrec it's just my own project.

Comment: @James_D the filled part and the curve are just one shape "CubicCurve"

Comment: @user3870075 Yes, I know. I'm arguing that to have the mouse behave differently for the curve and the fill, you will have to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see a particularly easy way to do this. I think that in order to have different mouse behaviors for the fill and the curve, you need those to be different nodes. So the idea is to create the curve and the fill as separate pieces, place them in a `Group`, and then use the `Group` in the display. Then make the piece representing the fill mouse-transparent.

Actually implementing that is a bit tricky; particularly getting a cubic curve that doesn't respond to mouse clicks in its "interior". The only way I could find to do this was to use a `Path` comprising of a `MoveTo`, a `CubicCurveTo`, and then another `CubicCurveTo` that retraced the reverse path (this ensures the interior is essentially empty). Then, as suggested, place that in a group along with a regular `CubicCurve` representing the filled portion.

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurve;
import javafx.scene.shape.CubicCurveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.MoveTo;
import javafx.scene.shape.Path;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ConnectingCubicCurve extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Circle start = createDraggingCircle(100, 100, 10, Color.CORAL);
        Circle end = createDraggingCircle(300, 300, 10, Color.CORAL);
        Connection connection = new Connection();
        connection.setFromCircle(start);
        connection.setToCircle(end);

        Pane pane = new Pane(connection.asNode(), start, end);

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Click on pane"));
        connection.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, e -> System.out.println("Click on connection"));
        start.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Click on start"));
        end.setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Click on end"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Circle createDraggingCircle(double centerX, double centerY, double radius, Paint fill) {
        Circle circle = new Circle(centerX, centerY, radius, fill);

        ObjectProperty<Point2D> mouseLoc = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        circle.setOnDragDetected(e -> 
            mouseLoc.set(new Point2D(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY())));
        circle.setOnMouseReleased(e -> mouseLoc.set(null));
        circle.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            if (mouseLoc.get() == null) return ;
            double x = e.getSceneX() ;
            double y = e.getSceneY() ;
            double deltaX = x - mouseLoc.get().getX() ;
            double deltaY = y - mouseLoc.get().getY() ;
            circle.setCenterX(circle.getCenterX() + deltaX);
            circle.setCenterY(circle.getCenterY() + deltaY);
            mouseLoc.set(new Point2D(x, y));
        });

        return circle ;
    }

    public static class Connection {

        private Path connectingLine ;
        private CubicCurve fill ;
        private Group group ;

        private ObjectProperty<Circle> fromCircle = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        private ObjectProperty<Circle> toCircle = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public Connection() {
            connectingLine = new Path();

            MoveTo start = new MoveTo();
            CubicCurveTo curve = new CubicCurveTo();

            CubicCurveTo reverseCurve = new CubicCurveTo();
            reverseCurve.xProperty().bind(start.xProperty());
            reverseCurve.yProperty().bind(start.yProperty());
            reverseCurve.controlX1Property().bind(curve.controlX2Property());
            reverseCurve.controlX2Property().bind(curve.controlX1Property());
            reverseCurve.controlY1Property().bind(curve.controlY2Property());
            reverseCurve.controlY2Property().bind(curve.controlY1Property());

            connectingLine.getElements().addAll(start, curve, reverseCurve);

            fill = new CubicCurve();

            fill.setMouseTransparent(true);

            group = new Group();
            group.getChildren().addAll(fill, connectingLine);

            connectingLine.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            connectingLine.setStrokeWidth(3);
            fill.setStrokeWidth(0);
            fill.setStroke(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            fill.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);

            fill.startXProperty().bind(start.xProperty());
            fill.startYProperty().bind(start.yProperty());
            fill.controlX1Property().bind(curve.controlX1Property());
            fill.controlX2Property().bind(curve.controlX2Property());
            fill.controlY1Property().bind(curve.controlY1Property());
            fill.controlY2Property().bind(curve.controlY2Property());
            fill.endXProperty().bind(curve.xProperty());
            fill.endYProperty().bind(curve.yProperty());

            fromCircle.addListener((obs, oldCircle, newCircle) -> {
                if (oldCircle != null) {
                    start.xProperty().unbind();
                    start.yProperty().unbind();
                }
                if (newCircle != null) {
                    start.xProperty().bind(newCircle.centerXProperty());
                    start.yProperty().bind(newCircle.centerYProperty());
                }
            });

            toCircle.addListener((obs, oldCircle, newCircle) -> {
                if (oldCircle != null) {
                    curve.xProperty().unbind();
                    curve.yProperty().unbind();
                }
                if (newCircle != null) {
                    curve.xProperty().bind(newCircle.centerXProperty());
                    curve.yProperty().bind(newCircle.centerYProperty());
                }
            });

            ChangeListener<Number> endpointListener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                Point2D startPoint = new Point2D(start.getX(), start.getY());
                Point2D end = new Point2D(curve.getX(), curve.getY());
                Point2D vector = end.subtract(startPoint);
                Point2D perpVector = new Point2D(-vector.getY(), vector.getX());
                Point2D control1 = startPoint.add(perpVector);
                Point2D control2 = end.add(perpVector);
                curve.setControlX1(control1.getX());
                curve.setControlX2(control2.getX());
                curve.setControlY1(control1.getY());
                curve.setControlY2(control2.getY());
            };

            start.xProperty().addListener(endpointListener);
            start.yProperty().addListener(endpointListener);
            curve.xProperty().addListener(endpointListener);
            curve.yProperty().addListener(endpointListener);
        }

        public <E extends Event> void addEventHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> eventHandler) {
            connectingLine.addEventHandler(eventType, eventHandler);
        }

        public <E extends Event> void removeEventHandler(EventType<E> eventType, EventHandler<E> eventHandler) {
            connectingLine.removeEventHandler(eventType, eventHandler);
        }

        public Node asNode() {
            return group ;
        }


        public final ObjectProperty<Circle> fromCircleProperty() {
            return this.fromCircle;
        }

        public final javafx.scene.shape.Circle getFromCircle() {
            return this.fromCircleProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFromCircle(final javafx.scene.shape.Circle fromCircle) {
            this.fromCircleProperty().set(fromCircle);
        }

        public final ObjectProperty<Circle> toCircleProperty() {
            return this.toCircle;
        }

        public final javafx.scene.shape.Circle getToCircle() {
            return this.toCircleProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setToCircle(final javafx.scene.shape.Circle toCircle) {
            this.toCircleProperty().set(toCircle);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , that was very helpful ^^.

Comment: YW. Please mark the answer as correct if it answers the question.